# Snackbar showing under a bottom sheet in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, snackbar, react-native-screens, react-native-actions-sheet

I am having difficulties with the snackbar and bottom sheet. I built a custom snackbar and used react-native-actions-sheet as the bottom sheet. I tried FullWindowOverlay, but it only works on iOS. Does anyone know of an alternative to FullWindowOverlay in Android? I appreciate your help with this!

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I guess you should try to use the Dimension API here: https://github.com/intergalacticspacehighway/full-window-overlay-native-header-issue/blob/main/App.js#L23

Comment: @AnNguyen still under the bottom sheet :(

Comment: Can you pus the full screen? What kind of navigator do you use ?

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/cooperka/react-native-snackbar

Comment: hi @MostasimBillah, I didn't use react-native-snackbar because the UI is different from the library and I can't modify it. That's why I created a custom snackbar

Comment: @MichaelBahl If this is what you I looking for, I used import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

Comment: Without a TabBar? Give us a full screenshot of a working and a not working version.